# Добавить всем товарам в opencart дополнительную категорию через sql запрос

Tags: mysql, opencart

как присвоить всем товарам дополнительную категорию category_id = 372

пробую sql запрос и получаю ошибку duplicate entry for key

INSERT  INTO `oc_product_to_category` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `main_category`)
SELECT product_id, '372', '0'
FROM oc_product;

в запросе нужно взять id  всех товаров из таблицы oc_product и добавить их в таблицу oc_product_to_category при этом в других колонках проставить категорию в которой будет товар и 0 так как товар добавляется не в главную категорию

- Возможная причина ошибки что в этой таблице по 3-4 колонки с одинаковыми id так как у каждого товара присвоено несколько категорий
  [image: Таблица oc_product_to_category]

Comment: попробуйте вот так ```INSERT INTO oc_product_to_category (product_id, category_id, main_category) SELECT distinct product_id, '372', '0' FROM oc_product;```

Comment: duplicate entry for КАКОЙ key? ключ у таблицы product_to_category (если вы не меняли ключи) составной (product_id/category_id) и в общем случае такую ошибку вы получите при попытке добавить запись с дубликатом product_id/category_id. Т.е. определённая запись уже присутствует в таблице product_to_category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я писал в комменте, у таблицы `product_to_category` первичный ключ составной - `product_id-category_id`. `Duplicate entry '50-372' for key 'PRIMARY'` - в таблице есть запись, где product_id=50 и category_id=372.

Если вы точно знаете, что ранее товаров у категории `372` ранее не было (или категории не было), то запись появилась в результате более ранних попыток добавить записи в таблицу. В таком случае найдите запись, где product_id=50 и category_id=372, удалите пробуйте вставку по новой. Но на всякий случай проверьте, может все необходимые записи уже внесены, это объяснит повторное появление данной ошибки (если таковое будет), но с другими парами `product_id-category_id`.
Можно также использовать `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
insert into yourschema.oc_product_to_category (product_id, category_id)
    select p.product_id, 372, 0 from yourschema.oc_product p
    on duplicate key update yourschema.oc_product_to_category.product_id = p.product_id, yourschema.oc_product_to_category.category_id;
```

В результате найденные дубликаты будут перезаписываться и `Duplicate entry` не возникнет.

Comment: Спасибо, да действительно ранние попытки все добавили